# How to Use IF EXISTS statement with OR clause in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We need to create a `script` which will `insert` only newly `created` `offices` and `districts` into the `Data table`. We need to check both `Office` and `District` `tables` for new `Records` and if data exists we need to `insert` them.

We have Tried out Below syntax for this,

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [dbo].[office] o
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Datatable] a ON (o.OfficeID = a.OfficeID)
    WHERE a.OfficeID IS NULL
)
OR (
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [dbo].[District] o
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Datatable] a ON (o.DistrictID = DistrictID)
    WHERE a.DistrictID IS NULL
)
)
BEGIN
   -- //CODE
END
```

But SSMS gives `syntax error` for this. How to achieve the above scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be `... OR EXISTS(` instead of `OR ( if EXISTS(`:

```
IF EXISTS
 (
     SELECT 1
     FROM [dbo].[office] o
     LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Datatable] a
        ON (o.OfficeID = a.OfficeID )
     WHERE  a.OfficeID IS NULL
 )
OR EXISTS
 (
     SELECT 1
     FROM [dbo].[District] o
     LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Datatable] a
        ON (o.DistrictID = DistrictID )
     WHERE  a.DistrictID IS NULL
 ) 
BEGIN
    //CODE
END
```